# Strange private memory behaviour in OpenCL

Tags: c, operating-system, gpu, opencl

This code breaks when the size of the private object exceeds 128 bytes. It only happens on OS X. Does anyone know what´s going on?

```
#define SZ 33 // Always works with 32 and below

typedef struct S
{
    int arr[SZ];
} State;

__kernel void myKernel()
{
    printf("sizeof State: %d\n", sizeof(State));
    printf("Threat ID: %d\n", get_local_id(0));

    State state = {{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}};

    for (int i = 0; i < SZ; i++)
        printf("%d, ", state.arr[i]);

    printf("\n");

    // uncomment this and it bugs with garbage output.
//  state.arr[1] = 111;

    for (int i = 0; i < SZ; i++)
        printf("%d, ", state.arr[i]);
}
```

Expected output is:

> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
>   5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
>   0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
>   9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,
>   13, 14, 15, 16,

But if I uncomment the line as noted the output becomes something like this:

> 8782104, 8782104, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256,
>   256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256,
>   256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256,
>
> 8782104, 111, 256, 256, 256,
>   256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256,
>   256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256,

Also, if I change the size to <= 32 (128 bytes) it always works.
printf is buggy on OpenCL OS X, but even without printf it changes the wrong values.

I have all the latest on a Mac Pro with dual D700 AMD cards. If I boot into Windows and run it there it works perfectly.

I'll say it's a OpenCL compiler bug, but I'm not sure, and I don't know how to get around it.

Comment: Did you mean `state.arr[1]=111;` ? As written, I can't understand the code

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you initialize `state` as follows? `for (int i = 0; i < SZ; i++) state.arr[i]=i;` Since I can't reproduce the issue here, I'm reduced to trying to rule parts of the code in or out

Comment: Yes =111. My bad.

Comment: Thanks Tim! That solved it completely. I can have any size if I initialise the way you suggested! Do you have any idea why? I'm not a C guru unfortunately. Btw, I found out that it bugs in my way for other cards/os:es as well, but with an exception and not silently like on AMD/OS X.

Comment: I don't know what was going wrong. Perhaps that particular compiler has an issue with large initializers. I keep counting and re-counting the list, expecting to find more than 33 members, but it still looks legit. And the "wrong" output you get.... that looks like `state` is now referring to a completely different region of memory, which implies stack corruption.code.

Comment: Tim, this also fixed the actual problem I had in "real" code, which this example was a distilled version of. Many thanks again, you've saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Randall suggested initialising with an empty State and then setting the members manually solves the problem.

So:

```
State state;
for (int i = 0; i < SZ; i++)
   state.arr[i]=i;
```

Comment: Once your issue has been solved, you should mark an answer (this one) as accepted so that it shows as solved from the list